# Are synthesized copy control members always public?

Tags: c++, c++11

When we don't define any constructors, the compiler synthesizes a default constructor for us. And the compiler will always synthesize the copy constructor, copy assignment and destructor if we don't define them ourselves. I want to know if the synthesized copy control members are always public? Or is there any way to control the access of these synthesized members?

**Edit**: To clarify, I want to know what the default access are for these members if I don't declare them at all.

Comment: They ought to be public I believe, else we won't have been able to declare class objects, or set them to other class objects. And the only way to change their access would be to overload, I believe!

Comment: @user007: You wouldn't want to declare class objects for classes that are only designed to be base classes. In those cases, you want protected constructors.

Comment: Note that these members are only synthesized if used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can get the synthesized special functions, but with different access controls:

```
class Foo {
  private:
     Foo() = default;
};
```

Since it's still *declared* private, it's not public, but you don't need to *define* it.

Comment: What are these members' default access if I don't declare them at all?

Comment: @Barry: It's indeed not the official term, but it's how the question was phrased. I don't think there is an ambiguity here.

Comment: @Rich: `public` as you suspected.

Answer (score 2):

They should be public

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor

> If no user-defined copy constructors are provided for a class type (struct, class, or union), the compiler will always declare a copy constructor as a non-explicit inline public member of its class

Answer (score -1):

The old way of blocking these member functions from being available for use was to declare them private yourself. Now you can just set the member functions equal to `delete`:

```
Example& operator = (const Example& rhs) = delete;
```

Comment: I think the OP is trying to keep the default implementations, just change them to private access (so they can still be called by members and friends), not remove them entirely.